# Remove even element in a set program not working (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
set = {1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
for element in set:
    if(element %2 == 0):
        set.discard(element)
print(element)
print(set)
```

When I run this program, this error message pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 65, in <module>
    for element in set:
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

I was trying to make a for loop that would remove even elements from the given set, and I was expecting it to remove all the even elements from the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid naming your variables after any python key words like `set`

You can avoid using loops, and use a set comprehension to filter the data as follows:

```
oldset = {1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
oldset = {b for b in oldset if b % 2 != 0}

//result: {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}
```

Comment: The question was how to make changes to a set; this does not do that.

Comment: @ScottHunter thx I have renamed the variables.

Comment: "Technically" this still doesn't make changes to a set; it assigns a new set to the variable that used to hold the old one, but the old one still exists unchanged.

Comment: @ScottHunter how would you do it?

Comment: Did you look at the other answer?

Answer (score 4):

Fix initial values in set before iterating, so that you don't change a structure you're iterating through. For example:

```
st = {1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
for element in list(st):
    if(element %2 == 0):
        st.discard(element)
        print(element)
print(st)
```

(Also avoid naming variables with reserved names, like `set`)